# Trying to get key and value from appSettings

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the information from my appSettings in my project, I'm using this so if I ever require to edit the information I can just change the app settings page, I want to extract the key and value as strings and display to a page. Heres my code. In the appSettings I have,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key ="General" value="someValue1"/>
  <add key ="Other" value="otherValue"/>
</appSettings>
```

In the controller page i have

```
namespace MyPro.Web.Controllers
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Models.MyPro;

    public class MyController
    {
        public ActionResult MyPro()
        {
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> myProData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
            var general = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["General"];
            var other = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Other"];

            myProData.Add("general", general);
            myPrData.Add("other", other);


            var myProModel = new myProModel(myProData);

            return View(myProModel);
        }
    }
}
```

In the model I have,

```
namespace MyPro.Web.Models.MyPro
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using MyPro.Model;

    public class MyProModel
    {

        public MyProModel(Dictionary<string, dynamic> myProData)
        {
            this.MyProData = myProData;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, dynamic> MyProData { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

and in the cshtml page i have

```
@model MyPro.Web.Models.MyPro.MyProModel

 <div class="content">

    <h1 class="sectionHeading">Contact Us</h1>
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyProData)
    {
    <div class="contentSection">
        <h2>Tables</h2>
        <div class="innerContentSection">
            <table class="baseTable">
                <thead><tr><th>Column1</th><th>Colum2</th></tr></thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr><td>@Model.MyProData</td><td>@Model.MyProData["general"].</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>@Model.MyProData</td><td>@Model.MyProData["other"]</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

My question is how do I get column1 to show the strings general and other and column2 to display someValue1 and otherValue from the values from appSettings, is it good practice to do what I'm trying to accomplish or is there a better way. I have tried other methods from stack using lists, hashtables etc. Is there a simple way to just grab or extract the data from the key and value.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Do you want to know how to pull all the AppSettings values into your data structure?

Comment: I'm looking to take the appSettings key and value and display it to the screen using the cshtml file where i have table body<tbody> tag so it displays as a grid like table display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use the AllKeys attribute of AppSettings.  For example:

```
    public ActionResult MyPro()
    {
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> myProData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.ToList().ForEach
        (
            settingsKey =>
            myProData.Add(settingsKey, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingsKey]);
        );
        var myProModel = new myProModel(myProData);

        return View(myProModel);
    }
```

As mentioned below, if you want a subset of keys to be output...
First add a new item to your config:

```
<add key ="ConfigItemsToMonitor" value="General,Other"/>
```

Then use this key to generate the list to output:

```
    public ActionResult MyPro()
    {
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> myProData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigItemsToMonitor"].Split(',').ToList().ForEach
        (
            settingsKey =>
            myProData.Add(settingsKey, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingsKey]);
        );
        var myProModel = new myProModel(myProData);

        return View(myProModel);
    }
```

You could decide to also monitor the value of ConfigItemsToMonitor - just add it to the comma separated list of values.  Make sure you exclude spaces.

Comment: This works but will going forward with future additions will it pull every key from the appSettings page?

Comment: I would expect so, though I haven't had the need and I haven't tested this scenario.  Why don't you give it a go and let us know the result?

Comment: Yea it does, sectioning off a portion of the appSettings could counter taking it all. I will leave it open for a couple of more hours and if no one else responds I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused - I thought your requirement _was_ to take it all?

Comment: No I only used a snip of code from each file rather than clogging up the whole page with non useful text.

Comment: Then can't you just have a list of the keys you're interested in?  ideally, add that list of keys as a config item.  I'll edit my answer to add an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will work

```
public class MyProModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyProData { get; set; }
}


var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
var myProModel = new MyProModel
{
    MyProData = appSettings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => appSettings[k])
};
```